# Human infrared emission resonance

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, biophysics, infrared-radiation, climate-science

I understand (please correct if misinformed),
the human body generates approx 100W of infrared energy, which seems (to an old engineer) an incredible amount of energy from a biological.

In recently researching EMF Climate effects, I would like to understand the energy outcomes to be expected with the inter-modulation of infrared (human emission) and microwave (EMF pollution) signals.

Also, can harmonic resonance be achieved through the summing of frequencies of both infrared and microwave energies?

Comment: What mechanism do you expect to lead to the human thermal emission modulating background microwave (or vice versa)?

Comment: Investigating if EMF effects may have a body internal 'weighting" factor or resilience, and if possible, a connection to the calcium channel ionization damage, other than the pulse characteristics of digital bursts. cheers

Comment: What does that have to do with "inter-modulation of infrared and microwave signals"?

Answer (score 3):

How much microwaves do humans emit? Humans can be viewed as 310 K blackbody emitters, and that [produces](https://www.spectralcalc.com/blackbody_calculator/blackbody.php) 0.000840649 W/m$^2$/sr across the 1 mm to 10 cm wavelength band. So the total amount of microwaves is essentially negligible.

The peak of the human spectrum is around 9.3 $\mu$m, way below the microwave spectrum, and the emission is incoherent of course. So the chance of seeing any harmonic interaction with waves 100 times longer or more is hence more or less nil.

Comment: Ah, numbers. Hard. Will fix.

Comment: Thank you for your most excellent answer, glad it wasn't going to be mathematically contrapuntal, cheers.